# Adding an index to a large table

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large table (~40 mill records) in SQL Server 2008 R2 that has high traffic on it (constantly growing, selected and edited...)

Up to now I was accessing rows on this table by its `id` (simple identity key), I have a column let's call it `GUID`, that is unique for most of the rows but some of the rows has the same value for that column.

That `GUID` column is `nvarchar(max)` and the table contains about 10 keys and constrains, index just on the simple identity key column.

I want to set an index on this column without causing anything to crash or making the table unavailable.

How can I do so ?

Please keep in mind this is a large table that has high traffic on, and it must stay online and available

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can-- not at that scale and with that kind of turnover. If you do figure this out, make sure to use a low fill factor on the index, or you'll kill performance from constantly re-building the index as rows are added.

Comment: Why would you store a guid in an `nvarchar`? And especially, why an `nvarchar(`**`max`**`)`?

Comment: You could use `ONLINE=ON` if your version of SQL Server supports it.  It's only available with enterprise I think though.

Comment: This schema needs redesign (honestly!). Many indexes hamper performance. You need to update all indexes after every DML query. There many things to consider, so if you ask this queston, it will be very popular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the answer to this one is easy (but you probably won't like it): You can't.

SQL Server requires the index key to be less then 800 bytes. It also requires the key to be stored "in-row" at all times. As a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column can grow significantly larger then 800 bytes (up to 2GB) and is also most often stored outside of the standard row-data-pages SQL Server does not allow an index key to include a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column.

One option you have is to make this GUID column an actual `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` datatype (or at least a `CHAR(32)`. Indexing GUIDs is still not recommended because they cause high fragmentation, but at least with that it is possible. However, that is not a quick nor simple thing to do and if you need the table to stay online during this change, I strongly recommend you get outside help.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer, i was afraid that would be the answer ... my nvarchar(max) column doesn't contain long strings (probably not more than 20-30 letters) , is there a way to convert that column to a different string type and than make an index ?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but creating a solution that works while keeping the table online will cost a few hours of development time for an experienced SQL Server developer. You basically can create a new column with the right datatype, trickle load that new column making sure that it stays in sync when the original data changes switch the app to use the new column and then drop the old column. If done correctly, this will keep the table online at all times, but as I said before, this is certainly not a simple process to implement.

Comment: `NVARCHAR(max)` is a LOB data type and stored out of the row straight away.

Comment: You can create a Clustered Index starting with `GUID`.

Comment: @Stoleg, the TEXT data type is always stored in the LOB allocation unit, however, depending on the size of the value a particular row's nvarchar(max) value might end up on the data page itself. But that does not change anything about that it can't participate in an index.

Comment: @SebastianMeine I agree about not participation in index. I'll check if `varvhar(max)` can be stored in row. What I know: `varchar(max)` is LOB, and LOB is stored out of row. I;ll check if I'missing something.

Comment: @Stoleg, see for example http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx